# Taylor expansion to second order

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find a Taylor expansion to second order to confirm a given result. I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to approach this problem and I'm not very experienced with Taylor expansions.

Here is the function is want to expand:

$$f_{+}(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\exp [\beta(\epsilon-\mu)]+1}$$

Here is the question:

Show that expanding $f_{+}(\epsilon)$ to second order in $e^{\beta \mu}$ yields
$$
f_{+}(\epsilon) \simeq e^{-\beta\left(\epsilon-\mu\right)}-e^{-2 \beta\left(\epsilon-\mu\right)}
$$

Can someone tell me what procedure I should follow?

I tried taking derivatives with respect to $e^{\beta\mu}$ but I think this is not the right way

Comment: You have to take derivatives with respect to the argument of the function (that is, in your case, $\epsilon$) and plug $e^{\beta\mu}$ then. Also, who is $\epsilon_i$?

Comment: @carciofo21 where would I plug $e^{\beta\mu}$, and $\epsilon_i$ is just the notation from the question, I'll fix that, it would be better to be just $\epsilon$

Comment: Ah, the old Fermi distribution!  You just need to substitute $x=e^{\beta \mu}$, find the Taylor series in terms of $x$, and then substitute back.

Comment: @sasquires Oh cool, I did that and it seems to have worked out, thanks!